# how to listen to a broadcast on -any- port within a linux distributed system

Tags: network-programming, distributed-computing

I am working on a distributed application in which a set of logical nodes communicate with each other.

In the initial discovery phase, each logical node starts up and sends out a UDP broadcast packet to the network to inform the rest of the nodes of its existence.

With different physical hosts, this can easily be handled by agreeing on a port number and keeping track of UDP broadcasts received from other hosts.

My problem is - I need to be able to be able to handle the case of multiple logical nodes on the same machine as well.

So in this case, it seems I cannot bind to the same port twice. How do I handle the node discovery case if there are two logical nodes on the same box ?? Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are:

1. Create a RAW socket and listen to all packets on a particular NIC, this way ,by looking at the content of each packet, the process will identify if the packet is for destined for itself. The problem with this is tons of packets you would have to process. This is why kernels of our operating systems bind sockets to processes, so the traffic gets distributed optimally.
2. Create a specialized service, i.e. a daemon that will handle announcements of new processes that will be available to execute the work. When launched, the process will have to announce its port number to the service. This is usually how it is done.
3. Use virtual IP addresses for each process you want to run, each process binds to different IP address. If you are running on a local network, this is the simplest way.
4. Define range of ports and scan this range on all ip addresses you have defined.

Comment: Option (1) would most likely require root privileges under most Unix systems (including Linux) in order for the process to be able to create raw sockets.